# Can I sign up for betas with multiple Battle.net accounts?

Tags: battle.net

Is it possible to have multiple empty battle.net accounts and sign up for beta testing? Or do you need a full version of a Blizzard game on every account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't use multiple free battle.net accounts to increase your chances of getting into a beta.

To qualify for a beta, you have to [create a beta profile](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/beta-opt-in-instructions) for a particular battle.net account, which involves running an applet that gathers system information from your computer. The applet will not download and run unless you have a paid Blizzard game license attached to that battle.net account. From the [Beta Opt-in Instructions](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/beta-opt-in-instructions) support article's Troubleshooting section:

> **Make sure that a game license is attached to your Battle.net account.**
> To download the System Check application and complete the opt-in process, you must have a valid Blizzard license linked to your Battle.net account. Trial game licenses do not qualify to lift this restriction.

The [Beta Opt-In FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/beta-optin-information) linked from that support article says this more explicitly:

> To opt in, you must have a full retail copy of one of the following Blizzard titles registered to your Battle.net account. Starter Editions do not count.
>
> - World of Warcraft
> - Diablo III
> - StarCraft II
> - Warcraft III
> - Diablo II
> - StarCraft Anthology

The exception is for the *Heroes of the Storm* beta. From the [Beta Opt-In FAQ](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/beta-optin-information):

> **Note:** The Heroes of the Storm beta opt-in does not require another license to be registered to your account. Any Battle.net account may be used to opt in.